# Make multiple select inputs that don't contain any previous input's selected options

Tags: javascript, jquery

### We start of with one select menu

```
<select>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
    <option>Option 4</option>
    <option>Option 5</option>
    <option>Option 6</option>
<select>
```

### With a button to add another option

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="AddNewField">Add Another</a>
```

### The Complicated Part... *-Updated*

With the ability to add a new option and maximum options being how many there is, I would not like the person to be able to add "Option 1" six times, instead the new appended option will not have the chosen field from the previous option, so if in the first option you choose 3, then in the second option you'll see a list only showing options 1, 2, 4, 5 and 6.

Additionally, if the person has added an additional two meaning three options are up there and they've chosen 1, 2 and 3 but then change the 1st option to 4, I'd like a loop to take away option 4 from all the options and add option 1 back onto the options.

I do hope this is more clear, I'm not only confused about the logic, but how to explain sorry.

### Example:

First Initial:

```
<select>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option> // We have chosen this one...
    <option>Option 3</option>
    <option>Option 5</option>
    <option>Option 6</option>
<select>
```

Second Appended:

```
<select>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
    <option>Option 4</option> // We have chosen this one so also removes from first input too
    <option>Option 5</option>
    <option>Option 6</option>
<select>
```

Comment: The complicated part, seems in explaining the problem.. My brain is hurting here, after just reading it twice :)  Could you explain in more detail, as I'm really not sure what your trying to do.

Comment: The complicated part is definitely complicated... Imagine I'm 10 years old. Could you explain it to me so I understand it?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu please let me know if my updated quetion helps?

Comment: You nearly melted my brain. So far we have: a button, an option selector, a "field". Please give us: starting markup > user action > expected result

Comment: @tmslnz does my edit help?

Comment: Try to open this: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9m62vuy1/3/) and tell me if its almost what you needed to function it to be?

Comment: @tmslnz yes, the first appended works upon appending, the first option does nto appear however if you change the first option it does not alter the appended element. It's along the way though of what I'm looking for!

Comment: Last attempt to understand you: are you try to synchronise two `<select>` inputs?

Comment: Oh, maybe I understand. No matter how many `<select>`s, you want to remove any option that has already been selected (in any selector) from _all_ other option selectors?

Comment: @tmslnz yes, and re-add any which have been changed and not being used :)

Comment: Store your possible values in an array, then each time a new selector is created remove its value from all previously created selectors as well as from the values array. Each time you create a new selector you only list the remaining options from the array.

Comment: @tmslnz would you mind submitting an answer mocking up a somewhat basic example please?

Comment: @TimMarshall how about changing select field to static read-only textfield with value selected and remove that selected option from the select and show that select field when user clicks add new option?

Comment: I have posted a fully working solution, have a look.

Comment: And when they change a previous select? :)

Comment: @epascarello My code handles that case

Comment: @TimMarshall Let me know if you have any trouble understanding what the code in my answer does, hope it helps!

Comment: @tmslnz sorry about the delay, I've been busy all day, just goijng over this now! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>Had a quick stab at it, adding options with remaining values.</del>

Here you go. It was a fun one. Hopefully the code is clear enough to read.

It allows to add as many selects as there are options. And it also allows to change any previous option.

<del>**Click the "Add options" text** to add more selects the example below.</del>

Example updated for clarity.

```js
var values = getInitialValues();

function getInitialValues() {
  return $('select').first().find('option').toArray().map($).map(function($el) {
    return $el.text();
  });
}

function getSelectedValues() {
  return $('select').toArray().map($).map(function($el) {
    return $el[0].value;
  });
}

function makeOptions(values, selected) {
  return values.map(function(value) {
    if (value === selected) {
      return $('<option selected>' + value + '</option>');
    } else {
      return $('<option>' + value + '</option>');
    }
  });
}

function makeRemainingValues(all, used) {
  return all.filter(function(value) {
    return used.indexOf(value) < 0;
  }).sort();
}

function makeInput(values) {
  var inputEl = $('<select>');
  inputEl.append(makeOptions(values));
  return inputEl;
}

function refreshValues() {
  $('select').toArray().map($).forEach(function($el) {
    var remainingValues = makeRemainingValues(values, getSelectedValues());
    var value = $el[0].value;
    remainingValues = remainingValues.concat([value]).sort();
    $el.empty();
    $el.append(makeOptions(remainingValues, value));
  });
}

function logValues() {
  $('.remain').text( makeRemainingValues(values, getSelectedValues()).join(', ') );
}

logValues();

$(document).on('change', 'select', refreshValues);

$(document).on('change', 'select', logValues);

$(document).on('click', '#add', function() {
  if ( makeRemainingValues(values, getSelectedValues()).length > 0 ) {
    $('select').last().after(makeInput(makeRemainingValues(values, getSelectedValues())));
    refreshValues();
    logValues();
  }
});

$(document).on('click', '#rm', function() {
  var $selectors = $('select');
  if ($selectors.length > 1) {
    $('select').last().remove();
  }
  refreshValues();
  logValues();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add">Add input</button>
<button id="rm">Remove input</button>
<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
<p>Remaining options: <span class="remain"></span></p>
```

Comment: For anybody doubting this excellent answer, you have to click the word 'Add' to add more `select` elements. At least, I didn't get that initially. I was looking at the code thinking 'well, this should indeed work, but it's not doing anything...' and then I kicked myself.

Comment: @amdouglas I have added a mention of this in the description, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Thank you so very much for this extremely useful code!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working alternative method as I have mentioned in the comment. It uses a list for the pre-selected values, but you may also use new select element with only the selected value and make it read-only.

PS: This is just an idea. Possibilities are limitless. BTW why don't you use [something like this](https://github.com/lou/multi-select/) instead which is more user-friendlier.

```js
var maxOptions = 3; // change this for maximum selection option.

$("#add").hide();
$("#options").on("change", function() {
  if ($("#selected li").length >= maxOptions - 1) {
    $("#add").hide();
  } else if ($("#add").is(":hidden")) {
    $("#add").show();
  }
});
$("#add").on("click", function() {
  var sel = $("#options option:selected");
  if (sel.val() != "") {
    $("#selected").append("<li>" + sel.val() + "<input name='" + $("#options").attr('name') + "' type='hidden' value='" + sel.val() + "' /> <span class='remove'>x</span></li>");
    sel.remove();
    $("#options>option:first").attr("selected", true);
  }
});
$("#selected").on("click", ".remove", function() {
  var val = $(this).siblings("input").val();
  $($(this).parents("li:first").remove());
  $("#options").append('<option value="' + val + '">' + val + '</option>');
  $("#add").show();
});
```

```css
.option-group {
  width: 200px;
}
#selected {
  list-style-type: lower-alpha;
  background: cornsilk;
}
#selected li {
  padding: 5px;
}
#selected li:nth-child(odd) {
  background: antiquewhite;
}
#selected li:nth-child(even) {
  background: aliceblue;
}
.remove {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}
#selected li:hover>.remove {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="option-group">
  <ol id="selected">
  </ol>
  <select id="options" name="options[]" required>
    <option disabled selected value="">Select Any</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
  </select>
  <button id="add" type="button">Add more</button>
</div>
```